# Not allow user to enter more then specific value on Input box Angular Change Event

Tags: javascript, angular, onchange, event-propagation, inputevent

When user enters an alphabets other then numbers then input box should not allow it. It is working in given example. But when user enters the numbers and if it is more then the specified value (i.e. maxValue) that time want to apply the stop Propagation. But it is not working.
So here user should not be able to enter other then numbers and also when the value becomes more then the specified maxValue then it should not allow the user to enter.

1. How to solve this problem ?
2. Why this is perfectly working for alphabets check and not working for maxValue check ?

Please find the jsfiddle link -

https://jsfiddle.net/d6aqn3g4/1/

code :

```
onInputChange(event) {
    const initalValue = event.target.value;
    event.target.value = initalValue.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, '');
        // here user can not enter any alphanets 
        // but here we wan user to not allow enter when value is more then maxValue
      if ( initalValue !== event.target.value || parseInt(event.target.value) > this.maxValue) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  } 
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Got the problem the issue here is 
event.target.value = initalValue.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, '');

This line is updating my input box value. because of that this is happening.

Comment: Problem is Resolved..